# How can I monitor or get a history of devices connected to my computer

Tags: usb, windows-8.1

I have a device repeatedly connect/disconnect. When in an application or watching a movie I'll hear the connect/disconnect sound.

I know [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) is an application that does what I want somewhat, but I think the device connect/disconnect sound triggers for more than USB devices. Is there another way that I can get which will show me a history of device connects and disconnects? I'm using Windows 8.1.

Comment: What USB Devices do you have installed? Are any of your USB devices powered by a battery? Are you using a USB Hub? Is the USB Hub powered by a separate power supply? Is it random when these reconnects happen? Can you recreate the problem? Do you happen to know how much CPU your using when this happens? I've seen some USB Security keys (used for software protection) that sometimes in high CPU loads the device will sometimes will disconnect/reconnect. Those keys are usually used in POS/Business Software.